# OV2640 with 18 Pins - No XLCK System Clock

Tags: camera

I'm trying to connect an OV2640 camera module to a microcontroller.

This camera module has only 18 pins as seen in this schema:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVBwV.jpg

Here an image of the module:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUVg0.jpg

These pins are on the module:

- 3.3V
- GND
- VSYNC
- SCL
- SDA
- HREFF
- D0 - D7
- DCLK
- PWDN
- NC

Maybe I could set XLCK and PLCK via the DCLK pin but I don't know how.

I am pretty new to camera modules and searched the net a lot of times. Most examples are for the OV7670. This module has also 18 Pins but all are used quiet contrary to the OV2640.

Could anybody help me connect and get a signal?

Comment: http://www.arducam.com/camera-modules/2mp-ov2640/

Comment: @Juraj thanks for the link, i tried these examples. But it's a different kind, the arducam version has an XLCK.

Comment: Can you be specific about which microcontroller you want to use?

Comment: @MichaelT i tried it with an ESP8266, ESP32 and RaspberryPi 3 Model B+. I used this example: https://www.instructables.com/id/OV7670-Without-FIFO-Very-Simple-Framecapture-With-/ and https://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-Connect-OV7670-to-Arduino-Due/ http://embeddedprogrammer.blogspot.com/2012/07/hacking-ov7670-camera-module-sccb-cheat.html These examples are for ov7670 but i tried to adapt them.

Answer (score 1):

In this specific OV2640 module, it's supposed to have a 12MHz oscillator in the board connected to XLCK pin (you can all time adjust the PLL trough SCCB interface as usual). Remove the plastic lens and see near the CMOS.
Regards

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes there is a oscillator right to the CMOS, i am a nooby when it comes to cameras with microcontroller. In all examples the XCLK is connected to a pin, i read that the XCLK could be "simulated" but i don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

I also bought one of these to use with an esp32, not realizing that there was an on-board oscillator and no system clock pin. I just left the pin on the esp that's supposed to connect to XCLK hanging, and set the frequency to 12000000 in my code. It seems to work alright!